# ADB over ethernet

Tags: android, adb, ethernet

I have an android device which I want to connect to using ADB.  For reasons that don't matter here I need it to have an ethernet connection, not wifi.  The device itself refuses to have both ethernet and wifi connections at the same time.

I have been using a third party app called ADB WiFi to connect to it with ADB when it is in WiFi mode, and I have found that I can connect to it in wifi, then switch the device into ethernet, and then reconnect to the new IP, and it works.

I would dearly like to be able to connect to my device (which is often remote and hard to reach) without first switching it into wifi and back, to which end I have written my own little app which uses SU and does:

```
setprop service.adb.tcp.port 5555
stop adbd
start adbd
```

It says that it is working when I run it and produces no error messages, but I can't connect afterwards.  It doesn't work in wifi mode either.  After setting up a connection once using the 3rd party app, I can then use stop adbd to prevent adb working, and I can use my application above to enable it again, without wifi or 3rd party intervention, which suggests that it is doing what it thinks it is doing, but missing a one off step.

Does anyone know if there is another thing that must be set / enabled / poked in order for adbd to work?  Does anyone know what I'm missing?

Thanks

Comment: Curious: Is ADB by Ethernet also available for linux systems?

Answer (score 5):

Have you tried this:

```
adb tcpip 5555
adb connect 192.168.1.1:5555
```

replacing the 192.168.1.1 with your phones IP Address?

Comment: Yes, of course, but it doesn't work until it is enabled on the phone also, and the question is how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get both ADB (through USB) and Ethernet, but it was device specific.  I used the Asus Transformer Pad TF701T with the keyboard dock.  The dock allowed me to connect the ADB cable and provided a full size USB port.  I connected a compatible USB to Ethernet adapter to get Ethernet.