Running an adb command on an android 11 tablet
I have an ethernet based meeting room scheduler I have repurposed to  use for Home Assistant using the companion app and fully kiosk. This works
I want to control the LED light on the side of the unit and the manufacturer proveded me with an adb command that should work,
I have the unit in developer mode but the debugging is either usb or wifi, is there a way I can force ethernet debugging on the device,
Or have it think a usb is connected and use tasker to read mqtt messages and run adb commands from the mqtt payload?
I have google so many times, I can’t find anything about forcing debug mode on, all guides point to “just use wifi man”

maybe this one? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20992363/adb-over-ethernet

Not quite, but that is fine, I managed to use shell as su to run the command
